# iOS Push notification distribution certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push-notification

I have a problem with distribution certificate of push notification. First I used developer certificate and push notifications works fine. Now my app is in app store and I use distribution certificate. I generated it in developer portal, create provisioning profile and subscribe app with this profile. Then I created certificate for server side and used it. If I send notification apple return connection OK but notification is never deliver. Where is a problem ? Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Make sure your server is connecting to the production environment and not the sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to generate a new certificate, it happen sometimes.

Thus, what kind of script do you use to send push notification ? if you use Easy APNS, make sure the "Production" certificate is selected for each device in you database.

Comment: I generated new certificate and one notification was deliver but other no.

Comment: Could you look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840431/push-message-doesnt-send-using-with-distributed-certificate